# How to unwrap lazy loaded entities?

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, lazy-loading

I'm using FluentNHibernate 3.2, I have a complex entity,
I would like to initialize an entity, with all proxies initialized.
I've used NHibernateUtil.Initialize and it's doesn't work I get, **`Session is closed!`** for all proxies.

Here is my mapping:

```
internal sealed class CityMap : ClassMap<City> {
    public CityMap() {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("Id");
        Map(x => x.Name, "Name");
        Map(x => x.AlterName, "AlterName");
        Map(x => x.ZipCode, "ZipCode5");

        HasMany(x => x.Streets)
            .LazyLoad()
            .ExtraLazyLoad()
            .KeyColumn("GovId")
            .Cascade.All();

        Table("Cities");
    }
}

internal sealed class StreetMap : ClassMap<Street> {
    public StreetMap() {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("Id");
        Map(x => x.Name, "Name");
        Map(x => x.AlterName, "AlterName");
        References(x => x.City).LazyLoad().Column("GovId");
        Table("Streets");
    }
}
```

**`Here is my invocation:`**

```
using (UnitOfWork.Start()) {
   // i get whole results until i need a Streets property      
   var source =_citiesRepository.Query.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Name.Contains(query));

   // here I've tried to use NHibernateUtil.Initialize like so...
   NHibernateUtil.Initialize(source); // <== here

}
```

When I try to get some Streets I receive an **`Exception`** that **`Session is closed!`**,
how should resolve this issue?

**I don't want to disable lazy loading...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lazy loaded entities always are loaded on first access by the very same session that got the object and created the proxy in the first place. When the session is closed and disposed, it obviously cannot do any more work, and in your case it means that it cannot load any further lazy load dependency.

There are 2 possible solutions, one is to keep the session alive for a longer period of time, so it gets a chance to load the object after the repository call. Another would be to make the repo load all the graph at once, eagerly.

By your code where you call the repo, you are using an `UnitOfWork` inside an `using` block. No idea about its internals, but I guess that object manages the session lifetime, and there is the main problem (correct me if that's not the case), since when you dispose it after exiting the `using`, hence the exception. You possibly need to keep the session alive, somewhere, for longer than this method for the lazy load to work. You might want to pass the `UnitOfWork` to the repository/service and let the caller manage its lifetime instead.

Comment: I do not control session life time, but I'm unable to understand how to prolong session life time?

Comment: You should really control how and when its gets created and disposed. Start by looking at your repository and unit of work implementations, and how they interact with the session, I guess you're just creating and disposing of it in the method you show, but trying to lazy load afterwards, so possibly a refactor to keep the session alive will be necessary.

Comment: Thanks I will check it out... and will get back with the questions or the answer.

Comment: +1 Thanks I've solved it! By prolonging the session I'm calling it from Service and not in repository, actually it's a good way to control the session. Thanks